# PHP how add an array to a Json not like string

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need add a jsonArray in my json, I'm use a php class (User.php) to model the json. like this:

```
 class User {
    public $id = "";
    public $nombre = "";
}
```

And I use other class (ArrayUser.php) to add the array from the class user to the final json

```
class ArrayUser {
      public $usuarios;
}
```

I use those classes in my code in this way:

```
$tempArray = array();
$ArrayUser = new ArrayUser(); 
foreach ($sth as $sth) {
       $user = new User();
       $user->id = $sth['id'];
       $user->nombre = $sth['name'];
       array_push($tempArray, $user);
}
$ax = json_encode($tempArray);
$ArrayUser->usuarios = $ax; 
$axX = json_encode($ArrayUser, true);
```

The result is this:

```
{
"usuarios": "[{"id":"1","nombre":"Leandro Gado"},{"id":"2","nombre":"Aitor Tilla"}]"
}
```

But I don't want the array like String (is not a valid Json by the way), actually I need my Json like that:

```
{
    "usuarios": [{
        "id": "1",
        "nombre": "Leandro Gado"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "nombre": "Aitor Tilla"
    }]
}
```

I appreciate your help.
Regards.

Comment: There is no thing like "json array". [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a text representation of some data structure. Build your data structure then pass it to [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) don't encode individual pieces (btw, the second argument of `json_encode()` is a number, not `true`). If the data structure you want to encode as JSON is an object then make its class implement the [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface. This way you can control what object properties are encoded and how.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I'm going to research more about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are json_encode -ing your data twice. Try this:

```
$tempArray = array();
$ArrayUser = new ArrayUser(); 
foreach ($sth as $sth) {
       $user = new User();
       $user->id = $sth['id'];
       $user->nombre = $sth['name'];
       array_push($tempArray, $user);
}
$ArrayUser->usuarios = $tempArray;
$axX = json_encode($ArrayUser);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It's almost there, only the array ($tempArray) left a comma at the end,  like that:
`
    {
    "usuarios": [
  
    {
    "id": "1",
    "nombre": "Leandro Gado"
    }
    ,
      
    {
    "id": "2",
    "nombre": "Aitor Tilla"
    }
    ],
    }
`
How could I remove that comma?